# Mounting Windows 8.1 hosted network volume on OS X Marericks 10.9.4

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, mount, network-shares

From a Windows 8 machine, I have shared an NTFS partition, full rights. On the Mac, I can access it as expected.

However, if I right-click on the volume and select `Make alias`, I will get the following message error:

```
The operation can't be completed. An unexpected error occurred (error code - 8060).
```

If I simply grab and drag it on the desktop, it won't complain. However, as soon as I access it, I get:

```
The alias "OS_X_Backup@W8" can't be opened because the original item can't be found.
```

If I push `Fix Alias...`, I can see my W8 machine's IP under the SHARED items, and selecting it will reveal the volume. However, if I click on it, the `Open` button remains greyed-out.

Searching online for answers didn't turn up any life-saving suggestion; this issue seems to affect older versions of OS X. Any tip appreciated; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting an Invalid Target, try setting the Finder's prefs to 'Show Connected servers on the Desktop'

[image]

Then right click Make Alias should work correctly [don't ask me why] ;-)

Comment: Although I wasn't getting an `Invalid Target` message, I was able to create an alias off of the newly-shown icon on my desktop, per your instructions. (Since this might help someone: in the original post, I kept it simple - didn't want to over-complicate things. This might all be an OS X 'noobiness' issue: my original problem was that the network drive wasn't visible in `SuperDuper`, that can't write dierctly over network, needs volumes mounted. Once I had the icon on the desktop, was able to drag it in Finder under `Devices`, and now SD sees it.) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome - as I say, I don't really know what makes the difference 'under the hood' only that this 'fixes' it ;-)